# Table attribute with FluentMigrator C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-migrator, sqlfilestream

I am trying to create a table that contains a VARBINARY(MAX) column with the FILESTREAM attribute. I don't know how to achieve that. Can you please help.

Documentation Pages You've Read So Far
Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/create-a-table-for-storing-filestream-data?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator) currently lacks support for the `FILESTEAM` attribute. But it is open source. Have you considered forking it, extending the `SqlServer2008Column` class and its touch points, and submitting a PR to the benefit of everyone?

Comment: This is news to me. I did not think about forking it before.